# Joining two tables in sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two tables in sqlite one table contains main categories and another is sub category

```
------------------
cat_id | cat_title
  1    |   cat_1
  2    |   cat_2
------------------

-----------------------------------
  subcat_id | subcat_title | cat_id
     1      |   subcat_1   |   1
     2      |   subcat_2   |   2
     3      |   subcat_3   |   2
     4      |   subcat_4   |   1
```

The expected result is

```
    -----------------------------------
       cat_1       |   cat_2
     subcat_2      |   subcat_1   
     subcat_3      |   subcat_4
```

can any buddy tell me the query.

Answer (score 0):

Lets call the main table table1 and the second table table2.

```
SELECT table2.subcat_title, table1.cat_title FROM table2 INNER JOIN on table1.cat_id=table2.cat_id
```

Comment: @AvinashMulewa: really? But you draw something else in your question

Comment: yes It is not the exact same result but the result can solve my issue

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that your second table have the ord (order) field, which denote order among main category

```
-------------------------------------------
  subcat_id | subcat_title | cat_id | ord
     1      |   subcat_1   |   1    | 1
     2      |   subcat_2   |   2    | 1
     3      |   subcat_3   |   2    | 2
     4      |   subcat_4   |   1    | 2
```

Also you have ord (order) table which can cover all your sub categories

```
-------------
  ord
     1      
     2      
     3      
     4      
     ...
     10000
```

In such case you can solve your task:

```
select 
   (select subcat_title from subcat where subcat.catid = 1 and subcat.ord = ord.ord) as subcat_for_cat1,
   (select subcat_title from subcat where subcat.catid = 2 and subcat.ord = ord.ord) as subcat_for_cat2
from ord
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!7/0e54c/2

Answer (score 0):

The expected result you are showing in your question is not really a valid table. Your result set cannot consist of a variable number of columns. You seem to want a result that contains a *column* for each category.

What you can do with [JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) is this something like this (assuming table names are `categories` and `subcategories`):

```
SELECT categories.cat_title, subcategories.subcat_title 
FROM categories INNER JOIN subcategories
    ON categories.cat_id = subcategories.cat_id
```

which will give you a result set like this:

```
cat_title        subcat_title
=============================
cat_1            subcat_2
cat_1            subcat_3
cat_2            subcat_1
cat_2            subcat_4
```

In your client code you can work with that result set and build a dictionary or whatever is the appropriate data structure for your needs to build the resuult you need.

---

A simple example of how to use the result set to build a dictionary using a `SqlDataReader`:

```
Dictionary<string,List<string>> result = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
/* suppose we have a SqlCommand command with the query from above */
using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    while(reader.Read())
    {
         string cat = reader.GetString(0);
         if (!result.ContainsKey(cat))
             result.Add(cat, new List<string>());

         result[cat].Add(reader.GetString(1));
     }
}
```